# Iphone> Uploading UIImage object to server via ASIHTTPRequest, photo name?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, asihttprequest, photo

I got a UIImage object with no name.
(but when I save UIImage to my photo library it gets a name like IMG_00000.jpg)

I just don't know how to use this name for request parameter. (or whatever name it is...)

That should be like,

```
`[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"%@.jpg", self.IDON'TGETIT]`
```

what can I use for name of this UIImage?

How can I make it? (property? is there protocol or something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourUIImage);
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"file"];
```

Comment: you can enter any name. You already loaded the image into the UIImage from your file. The first line in the code above makes it a datarepresentation of the image. You then upload the data and set the name arbitrarly in the _withFileName_ parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But I was hoping to that "anyname.jpg" parameter was something automatically generating IDs(or something like that).